# Entity Framework Many to Many association without FK

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So we have this legacy DB to which we have no control and cannot modify in any way or form. Any of the tables in said DB have foreign keys and we are using EF 6 to access it. We created our model and, up until now, things were OK.

Now we are dealing with the following, very common, structure:

```
[Product]          [ProductGroupDetails]             [ProductGroup]
ProductID          ProductID                         ProductGroupID
...                ProductGroupID                    .....
```

Both Product and ProductGroup tables have additional fields which are not relevant right now. The two fields in the ProductGroupDetails conform its primary key.

After adding these three tables to the model I manually added the associations between them by right clicking on the diagram and selected the Add New -> Association option.

After running the tt file I get these entities:

```
    public partial class ProductGroup
    {
        public ProductGroup()
        {
            this.ProductGroupDetails = new HashSet<ProductGroupDetail>();
        }

        public int ProdGroupID { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ProdGroupDetail> ProdGroupDetails { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class ProdGroupDetail
    {
        public int ProdGroupID { get; set; }
        public string ProductID { get; set; }

        public virtual Product Products { get; set; }
        public virtual ProdGroupHead ProdGroupHead { get; set; }
    }

   public partial class Product
    {
        public Product()
        {
            this.ProductGroupDetails = new HashSet<ProductGroupDetail>();
        }

        public string ProductID { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ProductGroupDetail> ProductGroupDetails { get; set; }
    }
```

I would have expected for the ProductGroupDetails entity not to exist, the Product one having a ProductGroups collection and the ProductGroup to have a Products collection.

Of course this makes it challenging when creating a new Product Group since to the new ProductGroup instance I would have to add an instance of ProductGroupDetail for each group but the ProdGroupID property would be empty since I do not know it yet. Normally I would just add instances of Product to the Products collection and upon save EF would work its magic.

Is there a way I can coerce the edmx so that the ProductGroupDetail entity is not created and the other ones end up having the expected collections?

Comment: Have you tried generating the edmx from the db connection? When I've done this, the linking tables (tables with only foreign keys) were not generated as a model. There must be a way to make the association, without creating the linking model, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Maybe this will help http://www.sirz.de/2014/09/22/entity-framework-many-many-database-first/ - I guess the name ProductGroupDetails is the problem and should be renamed to ProductGroupProducts or maybe ProductProductGroups depending on the primary key ProductId, ProductGroupId